# Ubuntu Apache https connection is taking a long time

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have an Ubuntu server 14.04 with Apache and plenty of capacity. Today the server is taking a very long to make the https connections. The main change today is a increase in traffic. I could not find conclusive information about what can be wrong.

Once the connection is done it's very fast processing the request.

The same request in http is very fast and this is an issue with many sites in the server.

You can check the difference by doing:

```
curl http://osvaldo.pt

curl https://osvaldo.pt
```

Here's an image from my browser

[image: Chrome Dev tools request]

Comment: I've just shutdown and restarted the server and it fixed it. I don't know how long... I had done this before and a few hours latter the problem come back.

Comment: It doesn't take long to start slowing the https requests, while the http continue to be fast,

Comment: if it is only a problem with `https` are you running out of entropy?

Comment: How do I check if I'm running out of entropy? Thanks

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31779/tool-for-measuring-entropy-quality

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, your server may be running low on entropy.

In my case, Apache would take very long (>20s) to serve pages via HTTPS, while the same pages over HTTP were fast as normal. Firefox would show nearly all of the long page load time as "Blocking" in the network console [[details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42327422)].

On the server, you can execute the following to diagnose the problem:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

If the values reported are routinely 100-200 or even lower, that will probably be your problem. In my case it was mostly <150 and even <50 after Apache finally served a HTTPS page. Others advise to take action for values <1000 already [[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged#List_available_entropy)]. For more explanations and a way to fix this issue with `haveged`, see [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged).

Also see this question: [Can having low entropy cause an HTTPS server to be slower?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335354/18163)